# Как сделать рандомную выборку из базы SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Я новичёк в изучении SQLAlchemy, да и Python в целом.
Интересует, есть ли какой-то стандартный вид запроса. который извлекает из таблицы рандомные позиции. 
Видел, что можно использовать .limit(x), где x - количество, которое нужно выбрать.

Есть предположение, что это можно сделать извлекая из базы по айди, а сами айдишники (рандомные) можно получить зная количество записей в таблице, и используя это число, как второе значение в стандартной функции random.

Но это костыль, и мне бы хотелось, если таковое вообще существует, использовать нативное решение.

Я делаю так:

```
lastnote = Products.query.order_by(Products.id.desc()).first()
print(randint(0,int(lastnote.id)))
```

однако, есть нюанс: если я удалю из базы позицию с каким-то айди, то в последствии, делая рандомную выборку, я могу получить число сгенерирвоанное `randint`, которое будет равно айди удалённой позиции из базы, и как следствие, я не получу нужную выдачу.

Подскажите, как быть?

Заранее спасибо.
Прошу прощение за глупый вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Из [комментария @Jayme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60805/getting-random-row-through-sqlalchemy/14906244#comment37849236_14906244) к ответу на [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60805/getting-random-row-through-sqlalchemy):

```
random_value = query.offset(random.randrange(query.count())).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию в `SQLAlchemy` с ее помощью можно генерировать выражения для работы с базой, следующее выражение быдет выводить рандомную запись из таблицы:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

lastnote = Products.query.order_by(func.random()).first()
```

А вот по ид может не работать, если записи в базе удаляются, пример - есть таблица с 1000 записей, но ид в ней от 100 до 200 и от 10300 до 11200

Comment: Старайтесь давать немного более комментированные/аргументированные ответы.

Comment: @tutankhamun
Исправил